# Nginx with Lua - how connection is processed when all workers is busy?

Tags: bash, nginx, lua

I have docker with nginx. Nginx run bash script via Lua:

```
    server {
      listen 80 default;

      location /sign {
        if ($arg_data = '') {
            return 404 '{"Error": "Param data is not set"}';
        }

        content_by_lua '
          command = "/root/test.sh " .. ngx.var.arg_data

          local handle = io.popen(command);
          local result = handle:read("*a");
          handle:close();

          ngx.print(result);';
      }
    }
```

Bash script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1h

echo "test"
```

I have 8 nginx workers, so on 8 http requests `ps ax` print

[image: ps ax]

1. Why on each worker 3 processes?
2. If I make new http request via curl, then I don't see error, I see connection hang. Who hold this connection, if all workers is busy?

Comment: Looks like you have a massive remote command execution vulnerability there. The client is in full control of the `data` parameter and you're passing it unescaped to a shell command.

Comment: It's test example for question demonstration.